# UDP packets not delivered - recvfrom() never returns

Tags: c, sockets, udp, fedora

I have setup a UDP receiver, as:

```
   int rx_socket;
   struct sockaddr_in my_addr;
   struct sockaddr_in rem_addr;
   socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(rem_addr);

   rx_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,  IPPROTO_UDP);

   my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
   my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
   my_addr.sin_port = htons(9900);

    rc = bind(rx_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &(my_addr), sizeof(my_addr));
    if (!rc) {
        printf("BIND SUCCESSFULL\n");
    }

    char buf[250];

    while(1) {
        printf("WAITING\n");
        recvfrom(rx_socket, buf, sizeof(buf), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&rem_addr, &addrlen);
        printf("RECEIVED\n");
    }
```

The recvfrom() never returns. I have done some Wireshark analysis, and it indicates the packets are there:

Summary:

User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 57506 (57506), Dst Port: iua (9900)

Checksum: 0x14a2 [validation disabled]

Data (8 bytes)

---

Any help will be appreciated.

EDIT:

An interesting observation is that the source, which is a DSP fails to send packets, i.e., sendto() returns -1, until I ping to it, from destination. Right after the ping, the source can start transmitting packets.

EDIT 2:

Here is the sender's code:

```
    int fd;
    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM,  IPPROTO_UDP);

    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;

    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(9900);
    inet_aton("10.0.201.102", &(my_addr.sin_addr));

    char buf[250];

    for (;;) {
        int bytesSent = sendto(fd, buf, 8, 0,
                (struct sockaddr *) &(my_addr), sizeof(my_addr));
        printf("sent: %d bytes\n", bytesSent);
        sleep(1000);
    }
```

Comment: What is the program's output though?

Comment: the first print to console: "WAITING"

Comment: OT: This `if (!rc)` is wrong! `bind()` returns `-1` on error, so it should be `if (-1 != rc)`. `0` is a rarely used, but valid socket descriptor.

Comment: Did you try telling `recvfrom()` to receive fewer bytes, for example only `1`, like so: `recvfrom(rx_socket, buf, 1, ...` ?

Comment: Yes, tried receiving 1, but recvfrom() is still blocked.

Comment: OK, wireshark shows port is correct - is IP correct?

Comment: Yes, both sending and receiving IP addresses are correct.

Comment: -1 != rc... such yoda much unsure

Comment: It is UDP, there is no guarantee that packets will go through at all...

Comment: The `sleep(1000)` looks wrong for a test app. I'm going to guess you've intended `usleep(1000)` unless you really wanted to sleep for 1000 seconds?

Comment: Also, does this work properly on a loopback interface?

Comment: Have you allowed the particular port in the firewall (which fedora enables by default ) ? Alternatively try disabling the firewall, `/sbin/service iptables stop` Does everything look ok in wireshark ? (it can show you whether the IP header checksum and UDP checksum is valid - turn on those settings. And check that the MAC address matches too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem turned out to be with virtualbox. My sender is on host, but receiver is on a virtual machine. If I run the receiver on the host as well, UDP packets are being received.